# Align to face normal vector

Tags: python

Help me rotation new object by normal a face other object.
I have code that works half. 
The axes at the selected polygon and the new object must be the same

code - http://pasteall.org/632513/python

scene - http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48131

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

code - http://pasteall.org/632513/python

scene - http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48131

Comment: The MathViz addon is very useful to visualize matrices, quats and vecs.  Is the normal axis in image above in local or global coordinates?

Comment: I do not understand ... The manipulator in normal mode
https://i.imgur.com/PnOisQi.png
I need the local axis of the new object to look the same as this normal

Comment: if you encounter some issue with 2.8 replace every "*" with "@" https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Align to vector using  [`Vector.rotation_difference(v)`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.rotation_difference)**

---

Altered the script from [this answer](http://import%20bpy%20from%20mathutils%20import%20Matrix,%20Vector%20%20obj%20=%20bpy.context.object%20matrix_orig%20=%20obj.matrix_world.copy()%20%20#%20for%20this%20example%20just%20pick%20the%20first%20face.%20axis_src%20=%20matrix_orig.to_3x3()%20*%20obj.data.polygons[0].normal%20#%20z-axis,%20could%20be%20any%20direction%20axis_dst%20=%20Vector((0,%200,%201))%20%20matrix_rotate%20=%20matrix_orig.to_3x3()%20matrix_rotate%20=%20matrix_rotate%20*%20axis_src.rotation_difference(axis_dst).to_matrix()%20matrix_translation%20=%20Matrix.Translation(matrix_orig.to_translation())%20%20obj.matrix_world%20=%20matrix_translation%20*%20matrix_rotate.to_4x4()) to find the quaternion rotation difference between the local z axis of the edit mesh and the normal of its selected (active) face.

Run script with target object in edit mode, one face selected and active. An object in scene named "Cube.001" will be located at face centre and oriented by face normal.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
import bmesh
context = bpy.context
obj = context.edit_object
mw = obj.matrix_world.copy()
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
# for this example jmake a face active
face = bm.select_history.active
o = face.calc_center_median()
# calculate the axis dif in local coords

axis_src = face.normal
# local z-axis
axis_dst = Vector((0, 0, 1))

matrix_rotate = mw.to_3x3()
matrix_rotate = matrix_rotate * axis_src.rotation_difference(axis_dst).to_matrix()
matrix_translation = Matrix.Translation(mw * o) # 

obj2 = context.scene.objects.get("Cube.001")
obj2.matrix_world = matrix_translation * matrix_rotate.to_4x4()
```

[image]
*Result of script. Moved cube in edit mode, showing local coords*.

Comment: Sumptuously! That's what I needed. Many thanks

Comment: Look at the top polygon does not work.
https://i.imgur.com/JqYfL7F.gifv

Comment: @ВладКиндюшов whoops, should have checked that.  Anyhoo, think I have it now.

Comment: I add ".inverted()" in to "axis_src.rotation_difference(axis_dst).to_matrix()" line 18
https://i.imgur.com/lSksTnW.gifv

Comment: But this is a bad solution for the cube. Perhaps there is a way that will work in both cases.https://i.imgur.com/DFP8mXu.png

Comment: And in some cases it does not work at all. Scene - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B44RnfYzKt3cZXdaX01wMGdsWWc/view?usp=drivesdk GIF -  https://i.imgur.com/5MYYzIb.gifv

Comment: Need to get some zzzzz's will get back to it.  Will look at logic,  might have to align to two axes.  Both methods align to normal Ok. align to normal with track_quot track to z and y up, and then align to x or y local with rot_dif.

Comment: Think using [BMFace.calc_tangent](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMFace.calc_tangent_edge) will give us the other alignment vector (that the normal axes are showing) to align object x axis to.  (can make the rotation matrix with `Matrix(norm, tangent, norm.cross(tangent))`.  Apologies.

Comment: Look. I want to make the similar addon for Blender - https://vimeo.com/36732689. If you are interested and would like to give me a little help than here is my email address Darcvizer@gmail.com It's going to be free.

Comment: Forgive me but could not give an example in the form of code? I do not how can I tell him how to work...

Comment: Sadly it does not work in Blender 3.1 anymore, I get the following error:

TypeError: Element-wise multiplication: not supported between 'Matrix' and 'Vector' types

Comment: does not work for me

Answer (score 6):

Alexander Nedovizin solved this problem

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
import bmesh
context = bpy.context
obj = context.edit_object
mw = obj.matrix_world.copy()
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
face = bm.select_history.active
o = face.calc_center_median()

axis_src = face.normal
axis_src2 = face.calc_tangent_edge()
axis_dst = Vector((0, 0, 1))
axis_dst2 = Vector((0, 1, 0))

vec2 = axis_src * obj.matrix_world.inverted()
matrix_rotate = axis_dst.rotation_difference(vec2).to_matrix().to_4x4()

vec1 = axis_src2 * obj.matrix_world.inverted()
axis_dst2 = axis_dst2*matrix_rotate.inverted()
mat_tmp = axis_dst2.rotation_difference(vec1).to_matrix().to_4x4()
matrix_rotate = mat_tmp*matrix_rotate
matrix_translation = Matrix.Translation(mw * o) #

obj2 = context.scene.objects.get("Cube.001")
obj2.matrix_world = matrix_translation * matrix_rotate.to_4x4()
```

Comment: From 2.8+ version you have to change replace "mw * o" with "mw @ o".
But it still does not work for Blender 3.2.

Comment: Lala_Ghost you need to replace all * with @. This solution is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had to modify Alexander's solution a bit to make it work:

```
import bpy
import mathutils
C = bpy.context
cursor = C.scene.cursor
obj = C.active_object
p = obj.data.polygons

#get the normal and center of the selected face
normal = obj.data.polygons[p.active].normal
center = obj.data.polygons[p.active].center

#generate a quaternion rotation from the normal vector
up = normal.to_track_quat('X', 'Y')

print(up)

#set the cursor to the center location and rotate it to match the up vector
cursor.location = center
cursor.rotation_quaternion = up
cursor.rotation_quaternion.to_euler()
#get the object world matrix
mat = obj.matrix_world

print(mat)
#generate the location and rotation
rot = cursor.rotation_quaternion.to_euler()
print(rot)
loc = mat @ cursor.location.copy()

obj2 = C.scene.objects.get("Cube.001")
obj2.location = loc
obj2.rotation_euler = rot

#bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location = loc, size = 0.1, rotation =rot)
#bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='ARROWS',location = loc, rotation =rot)
```