# Align to normal vector with python

Tags: python, normals, transform-orientation

I was looking to orient an object to a selected active face of another object in Blender 3.2.
[image]

Already found other similar questions, but none worked:

[Align to face normal vector](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93051/align-to-face-normal-vector) (took code from here)

[Align Object A to Object B to their respective active faces with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/138989/align-object-a-to-object-b-to-their-respective-active-faces-with-python)

[Python script get face normal, then set it as another object's orientation (Z-axis) accordingly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106763/python-script-get-face-normal-then-set-it-as-another-objects-orientation-z-ax)

The code so far(thanks to batFinger, slightly changed, since multiplication of vectors and matrices is now performed with a **@**, swince Blender 2.8+):

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
import bmesh
context = bpy.context
obj = context.edit_object
mw = obj.matrix_world.copy()
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
# for this example jmake a face active
face = bm.select_history.active
o = face.calc_center_median()
# calculate the axis dif in local coords

axis_src = face.normal
# local z-axis
axis_dst = Vector((0, 0, 1))

matrix_rotate = mw.to_3x3()
matrix_rotate = matrix_rotate * axis_src.rotation_difference(axis_dst).to_matrix()
matrix_translation = Matrix.Translation(mw * o)

obj2 = context.scene.objects.get("Cube.001")
obj2.matrix_world = matrix_translation * matrix_rotate.to_4x4()
```

The script expects a second object called Cube.001.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, correct script is:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
import bmesh
context = bpy.context
obj = context.edit_object
mw = obj.matrix_world.copy()
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
# for this example jmake a face active
face = bm.select_history.active
co = face.calc_center_bounds()
axis_src = face.normal

# normal to rotation:
rotation  = Vector((0,0,1)).rotation_difference(axis_src)

obj2 = bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"]

# Set Rotation:
obj2.rotation_mode = "QUATERNION"
obj2.rotation_quaternion = obj.matrix_world.to_quaternion() @ rotation

# Set Position:
obj2.location =  obj.matrix_world @ co
```

Comment: The script works, but if you test it on several faces on a sphere you see that the rotation does not always match

Comment: Oh. I think these 2 items need to be flipped: `rotation  = Vector((0,0,1)).rotation_difference(axis_src)`

Comment: How do you mean flip? Can you update your answer? :)

Comment: @Lala_Ghost I've updated

Comment: There are still a few degrees difference to when I face-snap a cube with "Align rotation to Target" enabled, about 1°