# how to find the angles to set the cylinder direction as perpendicular to the faces(polygons in python) of an object?

Tags: python, normals, mathematics

I want to find angle of an cylinder so that it will always perpendicular to the position in another object faces. I got face(polygon in python) position by 'bpy.context.active_object.data.polygons['index_number'].center' and each face also have rotation saved as 'bpy.context.active_object.data.polygons['index_number'].normal' . For the cylinder I also have cylinder angle by 'rotation_euler'.
In Attached photo the green one is fine. but the red one seems not perpendicular to the face. Anyone can help?
Thanks.

[image: figure 1]

Comment: I did not find related questions, if any then request to give link.

Comment: To little information. How do you get polygon number? How do you run the script? Why don't you use snap instruments?

Comment: That I can handle. Just run a for loop and find out new polygons with area range. For a particular polygon or face its position and normal is fixed. So using that information I want to set cylinder with perpendicular to that specific face.

Comment: Hello ! It may be your "get_perpendicular_angle" (or however you named it) function has a flaw. Could you post a snippet of the algorithm ? Also, you almost certainly will hit a roadblock once you start rotating or moving your objects in world space. Make sure you familiarize yourself with `object.matrix_world` which is used to transform from local to global space and vice versa

Comment: Do you change the position also? Just to make sure that correct face has been picked?

Comment: 'Gorgious' I did not use matrix. According to your comment it seems a little bit difficult.

Comment: "Crantisz" face selection is not problem. I can save their index number in a list and using that number to get specific face position to manipulate the position of cylinder when necessary.

Comment: Probable dupe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19533/align-object-to-vector-using-python   https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167514/15543  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27491/python-vertex-normal-according-to-world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger) comment, I checked those posts and try some variation and found my expected solution.
I used .normal.to_track_quat('Z','X') for each face to make it perpendicular and convert it .to_euler() for each face (or polygon in python). For example, if I want the cylinder to be perpendicular to face number 116 then code will like,

`polygon = bpy.data.objects['Circle'].data.polygons`

`cylinder = bpy.data.objects['Cylinder']`
`cylinder.location  = polygon[116].center`

`cylinder.rotation_euler = polygon[116].normal.to_track_quat('Z','X').to_euler()`

[image]