# How to get face normal's x or y axis vector (or matrix)?

Tags: python, normals, vector

### Is it possible to get vector of the x or y axis of face's normal orentation?

I know it's possible to get z axis of face's orientation like this

`bpy.data.objects["Cube"].data.polygons[0].normal`

However, I can't find a way to access x or y axis vector of normal orientation.

An expression like `bpy.data.objects["Cube"].matrix_world` (this express object local orientation) is also ok.

If these is no direct access, is these a way to calculate it?

[image]

Sorry for poor English

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/94047/15543

Answer (score 3):

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object
obj.data.calc_tangents()

print(obj.data.loops[obj.data.polygons[0].loop_indices[0]].tangent)
print(obj.data.loops[obj.data.polygons[0].loop_indices[0]].bitangent)
```

I could find a solution by myself.
Thanks!

Comment: For some reason when I tried this; I get: `RuntimeError: Error: Tangent space can only be computed for tris/quads, aborting` on this line `obj.data.calc_tangents()`